# Android - IntentReceiver Leak / Leaking / Leaked

Tags: java, android, android-activity, memory-leaks

The **IntentReceiver** is being **leaked** due to onDetachedFromWindow **not being called** in some circumstances.

```
@Override
 protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
  super.onDetachedFromWindow();
  mContext.unregisterReceiver(mScreenStateReceiver);
 }
```

This was discovered with a large amount of test devices and Android versions up to Android 4.1.1. I compiled using older as well the latest Eclipse 4.2.1, with a variety of SDK Tool versions up to 20.0.3.

Example **LogCat** can be found here:
https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/community/discussion?place=msg%2Fgoogle-admob-ads-sdk%2FVYSun9iD8tg%2FL3t6oSlrCbYJ

```
Activity myActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.adsdk.sdk.banner.AdView that
was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
```

Seams that this is a **known bug**:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=29399

**Is there a workaround? Thanks a lot in advance for solving this challenge!**

Christian

Comment: its better to unregister the receiver from onStop(), do :
 
        if(isFinishing()){
          mContext.unregisterReceiver(mScreenStateReceiver);
   
        }

Comment: Thanks a lot for your hint! I am using onDetachedFromWindow in a custom view as part of a library. So I can't use onStop directly and would rather the users of the library not have to handle this my making an extra call to my library during onStop.

Comment: I would recommand to create a public method, that users call to stop your receiver on the custom view. If you are using a CustomView for ads, i suppose that you have a method to start, so why not adding a method to stop. I know that it would be better to free resources implicitly but i think that adding another method call is better than a leak. Just be clear in your documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest not rely on 'onAttachedToWindow' & 'onDetachedFromWindow'. You could add paired operations like 'init' & 'destroy' to do these jobs like 'register' & 'unregister' BroadcastReceiver. Then you can have full control to avoid this type of leak.  Or, you could call onDetachedFromWindow explicitly.